# Laravel 8 eager loading

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I am running a project on Laravel 8 and am trying to eager load some data. The data get fetched as expected but the issue arises when I try to display the data to my blade.

My controller

```
public function siteHome(){
        
       $featuredArticle = Article::with('articleCategory')->first();

       return view('site.index', compact('featuredArticle'));
    
    }
```

The response from the siteHome() method which is correctly fetched

```
{
     "id": 1,
     "title": "politics",
     "author": "Andreas",
     "status": "published",
     "image": "testimage",
     "image_caption": "test image",
     "category_id": 1,
     "article_text": "test article content",
     "created_at": null, 
     "updated_at": null,
      "article_category": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "Politics",
                            "created_at": null,
                            "updated_at": null
                         }
   }
```

On my blade I want to display the author,status and an image from the articles table and also pull the articles category name from the article_catgeory.

In laravel 7 I would have extracted the article category name by looping through the data and fetch all the information and display it in the blade. The code below displays how I use to do it in laravel 7

```
   foreach($featuredArticle as $article)
    {
       //trying to fetch article_category name from the nested data
       {!! $article ->article_category ->name !!}
    }
```

the code above fetches the article category name correctly in laravel 7 but fails in loading the article category name in laravel 8. This is the error message I am getting

```
ErrorException thrown with message "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: /var/www/html/IkoNews/resources/views/site/index.blade.php)"
```

I expect it to be displaying

```
Politics
```

alongside other data as mentioned earlier on.

Comment: Could it be an issue with laravel 8 loading nested data or they have changed the way in which we pull data from a nested JSON??

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
foreach($featuredArticle as $article)
{
   //trying to fetch article_category name from the nested data
   {!! $article->articleCategory->name !!}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use another foreach because you've array inside another array or if there is one array you can use article_category[0] -> name or id which ever you wanted to.

if there is more than one article_category you may use another loop to get all that.

I hope it helps, if you faced any issue just let me know.